# Firestore security rules not working when using multiple levels of get() calls

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Been spending a couple hours on this - very frustrating.

I have an app with exactly the following DB - the `comms` documents are the items that users (who belong to groups which belong to depts) want to access, and comms are accessible only to the depts they list.

```
/users/user1   { group: /groups/group1 }
/groups/group1 { dept: /depts/dept1 }
/depts/dept1   { }
/comms/comm1   { depts: [/depts/dept1] }
```

(Can also post screenshots of these DB records if that's helpful for some reason.)

I'm seeing this:

[image]

Note how there is no line being highlighted as the cause, making this difficult to debug, but from lots of experimentation/simplifying example data, this seems to be triggered by the two levels of `get()` indirection:

- first we get() the user object to read the group,
- and then get() the user's group to read the dept.

If I simplify the DB to only need one level of indirection by making the comm ACLs in terms of groups rather than depts, then the rules work.

```
/comms/comm1 { groups: [/groups/group1] }
```

Even if I could get rid of depts, I still can easily run up against needing multiple levels of indirection - I simply need to inspect a field inside the group object, e.g.:

```
allow write: if get(user().data.group).data.isActive;
```

Here is the full rule code:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function userPath() {
      return /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);
    }
    function user() {
      return get(userPath());
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if userId == request.auth.uid;
    }
    match /comms/{commId} {
      allow read, write: if get(user().data.group).data.dept in resource.data.depts;
    }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example data you specify the user's group as

```
/users/user1   { group: /groups/group1 }
```

in your get you would be trying to access /groups/group1, what is missing here is the /databases/$(database)/documents path and most probably that is why your get isn't returning anything.

Comment: So, if you replace get(user().data.group).data.dept with 
get(/databases/$(database)/documents//groups/group1) does it work?

Comment: It's a DocumentReference. I had tried padding with the prefix as well, and also verify that it's == /databases/$(database)/documents/groups/group1, but still doesn't work. (Adding this info to the question.) Did you try this and did this work for you?

Comment: I've clarified my question, but the line in your comment does not perform two get()s - you're just hard-coding groups/group1 instead of reading it out of the user object (which is what I need to do). And (consistent with my question) a single get() works fine.